# WPF Binding Breaks on Parent Collapse

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am working with wpf and xaml binding a visibility property to a dependency property however when the parent object collapses the binding breaks and I cant figure out why.  If I recreate the binding in code after the parent collapses and becomes visible again the process works however that is ugly and defeats the purpose of the binding.  Here is a small wpf project that will reproduce the problem.

```
<Window x:Class="RibbonExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" KeyUp="Window_KeyUp">
    <Grid>

        <r:Ribbon Grid.Row="0" x:Name="xRibbon" Title="Ribbon Example">
            <r:RibbonTab x:Name="View" Header="Tab" IsSelected="True">
                <r:RibbonGroup Header="Visible">
                    <r:RibbonTextBox x:Name="xButton" Text="Visible Text" />
                </r:RibbonGroup>

                <r:RibbonGroup Header="Invisible" Visibility="{Binding VisibilityDependancy}">
                    <r:RibbonTextBox x:Name="xButton2" Text="{Binding VisibilityDependancy}" />
                </r:RibbonGroup>
            </r:RibbonTab>
        </r:Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the codebehind.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace RibbonExample
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty VisibilityDependancyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("VisibilityDependancy", typeof(Visibility), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Collapsed));

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            SetValue(VisibilityDependancyProperty, Visibility.Visible);
        }

        private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            SetValue(VisibilityDependancyProperty, Visibility.Collapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

To reproduce simple focus the window, press a key and the collapsed RibbonGroup should become visible then when you release it will hide.  If you collapse the ribbon by double clicking on the tab header "Tab" then bring it back up the binding will no longer work, the visibility of the RibbonGroup will remain in whatever state it was in before you collapsed the ribbon.

Interestingly the binding doesn't break if you do IsEnabled and set it to true or false, only if you are binding a visibility behind the Ribbon.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Binding is breaking since in your code behind on key down events you are explicitly setting value for Dependency Property by calling `SetValue` method.

Instead you should use `SetCurrentValue` in case you want `to retain your bindings` apart from setting it manually from code behind.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx) for SetCurrentValue -

> This method is used by a component that programmatically sets the
>   value of one of its own properties without disabling an application's
>   declared use of the property. The SetCurrentValue method changes the
>   effective value of the property, but existing triggers, data bindings,
>   and styles will continue to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Changing my use of setvalue to setcurrentvalue however does not fix the problem.  It works until the ribbon collapses.